# PHP folder creation (mkdir) fail when using variable with slash in it

Tags: php, linux, directory-structure

I have application with cases ids structured with `/` in them, example: `F-4/1`, I am making upload script and making a folder for each case and it is failing on every `/`.

for `F-4/1` it will make `F-4` folder.

```
$prikaz8 ="F-4/1";

if (!file_exists('uploads/'.$prikaz8)) {
    mkdir('uploads/'.$prikaz8, 0777, true);
}
```

I tried escaping it but didn't work. I can not find any information on this and how to solve it, please advise.

When I make them manually, I have it mounted over `sshfs`  it lets me create it. I know I can replace `/` with something else, but I would like to keep case number the same. Would I even be able to target such folder with PHP later after creation?

[image]

Comment: Odd.. What cmd did you run over ssh `mkdir -p F-4/1`? File names cannot/should not contain '/', whats `ls -la uploads/` show, I pretty sure it wont be `/` (looks like thunar is showing nested folder if only one folder, but thats odd too)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I used OS X, not Linux to create it, i have disk mounted with `sshfs`, not `ssh` but I seen now on Linux it gets translated to  `:`, but on OS X its shown like `/`. Yeah i can not do that...

Comment: if you store the filename in a db you can then call it what you like, store it with normalised filenames

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah i will have to save info anyway. So I will just sanitize everything. The fact that OS X let me create it got my hopes up and confused me. I will have to adjust this based on servers, because this app will end up in-house on different servers. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux enviorment "/" used for seperators, hence we cant use it in file Or dir name.
there is already answer for it. Kindly refer it this. [click here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328928/how-to-create-a-directory-with-in-unix)